# has MetaData yet the class cant be found

Tags: maven, jpa, many-to-many, datanucleus

Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE", 
uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"EMPNO"}) })
public class Employee implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name="EMPNO")
private String empNo;
@Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
private String firstName;
@Column(name="midInit")
private char midInit;
@Column(name="LASTNAME")
private String lastName;
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id.employee")
Set<EmployeeSchedule> schedules;
.....
```

Schedule.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SCHEDULE_SLOT", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint      
  (columnNames=        {"SLOTNO"})})
public class ScheduleSlot implements Serializable{
@Id @Column(name="SLOTNO")
private String slotNo;
@Column(name="SLOTSTART")
private Date slotStart;
@Column(name="SLOTEND")
private Date slotEnd;
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="id.schedule")
private Set<Employee> employees ;//= new HashSet<Employee>() ;
....
```

EmployeeSchedule.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE_SCHEDULE")
@AssociationOverrides(
    { @AssociationOverride 
        (   name = "id.employee", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "empNo")), 
      @AssociationOverride
        (   name = "id.schedule", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "slotNo"))     
    }) 
public class EmployeeSchedule {
@EmbeddedId 
EmployeeSchedulePK id;
@Column(name="available")
private boolean available;
@Column(name="UPDATEDON")
private Date updatedOn;
@Column(name="UPDATEDBY")
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="updatedBy")
private String updatedBy;

public EmployeeSchedule() {}

public EmployeeSchedule(EmployeeSchedulePK id) {
    this.id = id;
}
......
```

EmployeeSchedulePK .java

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeSchedulePK implements Serializable {
@ManyToOne 
private Employee employee;
@ManyToOne 
private ScheduleSlot schedule;
public EmployeeSchedulePK() {
}
```

...

When doing maven install I get the following error. Please advice.. thanks

DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.1.0.release) : Enhancement of classes
Class "com.co.dsp.iwork.entity.EmployeeSchedule" has MetaData yet the class cant be found. Please check your CLASSPATH specifications.
DataNucleus Enhancer completed with an error. Please review the enhancer log for full details. Some classes may have been enhanced but some caused errors
the dataneucleaus log shows: -
Class "com.co.dsp.iwork.entity.EmployeeSchedule" : Populating Meta-Data
13:22:59,059 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Class "com.co.dsp.iwork.entity.EmployeeSchedule" field "employee" : adding Meta-Data for field embedded in class "com.co.dsp.iwork.entity.EmployeeSchedulePK" since it didnt appear in the  Meta-Data definition.
13:22:59,059 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Class "com.co.dsp.iwork.entity.EmployeeSchedule" field "schedule" : adding Meta-Data for field embedded in class "com.co.dsp.iwork.entity.EmployeeSchedulePK" since it didnt appear in the  Meta-Data definition.
**13:22:59,060 (main) ERROR [DataNucleus.MetaData] - **Class "com.co.dsp.iwork.entity.#UNKNOWN.id" has MetaData yet the class cant be found.*** Please check your CLASSPATH specifications.*
13:22:59,061 (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidClassMetaDataException: Class "com.co.dsp.iwork.entity.EmployeeSchedule" has MetaData yet the class cant be found. Please check your CLASSPATH specifications.
13:22:59,063 (main) ERROR [DataNucleus.Enhancer] - DataNucleus Enhancer completed with an error. Please review the enhancer log for full details. Some classes may have been enhanced but some caused errors
Class "com.co.dsp.iwork.entity.EmployeeSchedule" has MetaData yet the class cant be found. Please check your CLASSPATH specifications.
org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidClassMetaDataException: Class "com.co.dsp.iwork.entity.EmployeeSchedule" has MetaData yet the class cant be found. Please check your CLASSPATH specifications.
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.ClassMetaData.populateMemberMetaData(ClassMetaData.java:464)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.ClassMetaData.populate(ClassMetaData.java:210)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager$1.run(MetaDataManager.java:2699)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.populateAbstractClassMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2693)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.populateFileMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2516)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseFileMetaDataForUse(MetaDataManager.java:1123)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManager.java:986)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:793)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:525)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1258)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractDataNucleusMojo.executeInJvm(AbstractDataNucleusMojo.java:333)
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractEnhancerMojo.enhance(AbstractEnhancerMojo.java:249)
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractEnhancerMojo.executeDataNucleusTool(AbstractEnhancerMojo.java:72)
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractDataNucleusMojo.execute(AbstractDataNucleusMojo.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

POM.xml :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.co.dsp</groupId>
<artifactId>dsp.dsp-iwork</artifactId>
<version>0.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>DSP-iWork</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    <dsp.version>0.6.0-SNAPSHOT</dsp.version>
    <equinox.ver>3.7.0.v20110613</equinox.ver>
<spring.maven.artifact.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.maven.artifact.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
    <spring.osgi.version>1.2.1</spring.osgi.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency><groupId>com.co.dsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsp.kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${dsp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency><groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency><dependency><groupId>com.co.dsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsp.dsi.das.dbconnection</artifactId>
        <version>${dsp.version}</version>
    </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>com.co.dsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsp.dsi.das.core</artifactId>
        <version>${dsp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><groupId>com.co.dsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsp.dsi.das.api</artifactId>
        <version>${dsp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><groupId>com.co.dsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsp.dsi.dups.core</artifactId>
        <version>${dsp.version}</version>
    </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>com.co.dsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsp.dsi.dups.api</artifactId>
        <version>${dsp.version}</version>
    </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>com.co.dsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsp.dsi.scheduler</artifactId>
        <version>${dsp.version}</version>
    </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>com.co.dsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>das-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${dsp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository><id>nexus</id>
<url>http://sjc1ssadsp01.crd.co.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>nexus</id>
<url>http://sjc1ssadsp01.crd.co.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-repo</id>
        <name>maven repo</name>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone</id>
<name> SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Milestone 
Releases</name>
<url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build><plugins><plugin>
<groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.1</version>
<configuration>
<fork>false</fork>
<log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
<verbose>true</verbose>
<enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
<persistenceUnitName>WorkPersistenceUnit</persistenceUnitName>
</configuration><executions><execution>
<phase>compile</phase><goals><goal>enhance</goal></goals></execution></executions>
</plugin><plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.7</version>
<extensions>false</extensions><executions>  <execution>
<id>bundle</id> <phase>package</phase><goals>
<goal>bundle</goal></goals></execution></executions>
<configuration>
<instructions>
<Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
<Bundle-Name>DSP iWork Integration</Bundle-Name>
<Bundle-Version>${dsp.version}</Bundle-Version>
<Bundle-Classpath>.</Bundle-Classpath>
<Import-Package>javax.persistence,com.co.dsp.dsi.scheduler,org.apache.log4j,
com.co.dsp.kernel.spi;version="0.3",com.co.dsp.kernel.util;version="0.3",
com.co.dsp.dsi.dups.api;version="0.3",com.co.dsp.dsi.dups.constants;version="0.3",
com.co.dsp.dsi.dups.exception,com.co.dsp.dsi.config,org.springframework.beans.factory,
org.springframework.osgi.context,org.springframework.osgi.util,
org.osgi.framework;version="1.5",com.co.dsp.dsi.das.api,javax.jdo, 
javax.jdo.identity, javax.jdo.spi</Import-Package></instructions></configuration>
</plugin></plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**updating partial message after executing: mvn clean process-classes -X**

```
   [DEBUG]Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\502128830\.m2
\repository\asm\asm\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG]Could not find metadata asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml in 
com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone 
(http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone)
[DEBUG]Could not find metadata asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml in DN_M2_Repo 
(http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/)
[WARNING]Could not transfer metadata asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from/to 
local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk): No connector available to access 
repository     local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk) of type leg
acy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
org.sonatype.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata 
asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from/to local.repository         
(file:../../local.repository/trunk): No connector available to access repository 
local.repository (
file:../../local.repository/trunk) of type legacy using the available factories 
WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run
(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:588)
        at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run
(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: No connector 
available to access repository local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk) 
of     type legacy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnec
torFactory
        at 
org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.getRepositoryConnector
(DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.java:400)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run
(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:559)
        ... 4 more
[DEBUG]Could not find metadata asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\502128830
\.m2\repository)


[INFO]--- maven-datanucleus-plugin:3.0.1:enhance (default) @ dsp.dsp-iwork ---
[DEBUG]Could not find metadata org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core/maven-metadata.xml in 
local (C:\Users\502128830\.m2\repository)
 [WARNING]Could not transfer metadata asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from/to 
local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk): No connector available to access 
repository     
local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk) of type leg
acy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
org.sonatype.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata 
asm:asm/maven-metadata.xml from/to local.repository     
(file:../../local.repository/trunk): No connector available to access repository 
local.repository (
file:../../local.repository/trunk) of type legacy using the available factories 
WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run
(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:588)
at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run
(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: No connector 
available to access repository local.repository (file:../../local.repository/trunk) 
of  type legacy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnec
torFactory
        at 
org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.getRepositoryConnector
(DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.java:400)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run
(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:559)
        ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your pom ?

You want to work on bytecode with DataNucleus Enhancer.

Your plugin is bound to compile phase, which is wrong, as it works on compiled classes.

You should bind it to process-classes instead.

Comment: Ok, you should bind it to <phase>process-classes</phase> instead of compile

Comment: So you have <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
in your pom? Could you please run "mvn clean process-classes -X" and post the result ?

Comment: Yes pom now has  : <executions>
     <execution>
      <phase>process-classes</phase>
<!--       <phase>compile</phase>  -->
      <goals>
       <goal>enhance</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>

Comment: the output message on executing mvn clean process-classes -X is more about 290000 which is more then what stackoverflow supports. I m not able to fine any way to attach. Is there any id I can email you?

Comment: i have updated this message with partial output... thank you so much for your help lookinginto this issue.

Comment: Ok, not easy to debug remotely :-) When you run mvn clean compile (or mvn clean process-classes) Do you see the .class file in target/classes/com/co/dsp/iwork/entity/ (EmployeeSchedule.class)